# cannot resolve method increment in firestore (error:cannnot find symbol method Increment(int))

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I can't get this code to work:

```
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.model.value.FieldValue;

private FirebaseFirestore db;

public void onCreate(){
...
db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
...
}

private void increment() {
        DocumentReference washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC");

        // Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
        washingtonRef.update("population", FieldValue.increment(50));
    }
```

I tried using both:

```
com.google.firebase.firestore

com.google.firebase.firestore.model.value
```

but it still doesn't work

when I tried to build this,I get an error:

> cannot find symbol method increment(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct class is [`com.google.firebase.firestore.FieldValue`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/FieldValue.html#increment(double)).

If using that path doesn't show you an `increment` method, you're most likely using a version of the SDK that doesn't include that method yet. Check your gradle file, and upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: thanks, I changed the SDK version from 17.1.2 to 21.3.0, I used the importation of firebase from tools>firebase don't know why it used an older version.